# High availability and clustering in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, load-balancing, devops

I read that SonarQube is going to provide high availability and clustering from 6.x version. But I couldn't seen any document related to the procedure of it. Overall, how does the high availability and clustering work with SonarQube 5.6.6 version and latest 6.X versions?

Is there any difference between these two in High availability and is there any high level modifications does between 5.5 and 6.X version of SonarQube?

Answer (score 2):

SonarQube 5.6* will scale vertically; throw more hardware at it and it will use that hardware well.

SonarQube 6.x will eventually scale horizontally as well; throw more nodes at it and it will use them well. But this feature won't be available in the Community Edition - it will be available only for customers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Is there any option like disaster recovery for sonarqube @G.Ann

Comment: ...regular database backups @ross?